# When to use pointers in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am learning how to create iPhone apps and I have seen that most of the variables we create store memory addresses (pointers) instead than holding the actual value or object. I also have found out that every time you declare a variable with the pointer char (`*`) you know that the variable is going to hold the address and whenever you don't use the (`*`) mark to declare a variable you know that it will hold the value instead than the memory location. But I don't know when to us which. for example I have:

```
CGFloat someVar = [image1 alpha];  // This variable does not require *
                                   // image 1 is a: IBOutlet UIImageView
```

and in this other case I have to use a pointer:

```
UIViewController *someOtherVar = [[UIViewController alloc] init];  // this type of var requires *
```

It will be nice if I can know when can I use each instead of trying each until project compiles.

Comment: You could read the documentation. The first Google result for `UIViewController` is [the `UIViewController` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The return type is indicated for each method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function and method signatures in the headers and documentation will indicate what the type is.

For example, here is how the `alpha` property is declared for `UIView`:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat alpha;
```

There is no `*` anywhere, so you know it returns `CGFloat` and not `CGFloat*`.

In contrast, the `backgroundColor` property is declared like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor;
```

so you know it will return `UIColor*` (a pointer).

Some things are declared with a type of `id`, which is always going to be a pointer to an object.

In general, Objective-C objects (types declared with `@interface`) will always be referenced as pointers, while primitive C types and `structs` will often (but not always) be passed and returned by value.

Answer (score 1):

Oversimplifying greatly, but it depends on the data being returned.

From your examples, `CGFloat` is a wrapper for `float`, which is a *primitive* C data type. `[image1 alpha]` returns a `CGFloat`. `UIViewController` is an object type. `[[UIViewController alloc] init]` returns a pointer to this allocated memory, `(UIViewController *)`. Therefore you need to use the pointer.

Pointers can be used in more cases than can be described. Generally speaking, as you are starting out, you typically use pointers for objects. But I encourage you to [check the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) to determine the exact data type. It will provide *hints* as to the data type returned by a specific method or property.